# Is there a way to see the url addreses on Jupyter notebook when read a CSV file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter

I have a dataset in a CSV file. There is a 'Link' column and its values are clickable links with the same general name ‘source’, but they are different websites.

When I read the file on Jupyter notebook using Python ‘pd.read_csv’, the data frame shows the Link column with all the values same string, ‘source’ and no link.

Is there a way I can see the URL addresses on Jupyter notebook instead of the word ‘source’?

Answer (score 1):

You might find some helpful information here: https://datascientyst.com/create-clickable-link-pandas-dataframe-jupyterlab/. This link suggests you convert the DF to HTML and output that in your jupyter notebook. More specifically, you can view the major takeaway here:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(df.to_html(render_links=True, escape=False))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i tried this and it didn`t work, still the values are just string('source') no link.